# How to associate ResultSet with a cursor declared in oracle package specification?

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, plsql

How can I retrieve results in java from a cursor defined in a pl/sql package specification as:

```
create or replace package test_package_1 as
  cursor cur_1 is
    select dummy 
    from dual;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to define (and pass out as a parameter) a ref cursor.

You might find [this](http://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/using-ref-cursors-to-return-recordsets.php) to be of use.

Comment: Your suggestion is to create a subroutine with out parameter of ref cursor type. But I was asking how to associate a ResultSet with a cursor declared directly in a package specification and not returned by a subroutine.

Comment: You can't. The only way you can pass a cursor around as a parameter (which is what you'd need to be able to pass it back to Java) is by declaring a ref cursor and passing that back.